# Popup from code behind in WPF not working ( On resize and switching windows)

Tags: wpf, button, popup, code-behind

**I want to add a popup on click of a Button in WPF. I dont want to add Popup code in my XAML. It has to be code behind.**

My XAML is as follows::

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
   <Grid>
     <Button x:Name="button1" Click="button1_Click">Button</Button>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

My XAML file has a simple button. On click of Button, I am trying to execute the following code.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;

        Popup codePopup = new Popup();
        TextBlock popupText = new TextBlock();
        popupText.Text = "Popup Text";
        popupText.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
        popupText.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
        codePopup.Child = popupText;

        codePopup.PlacementTarget = button;
        codePopup.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

But why is the popup not **attaching itself to the window**. I mean the popup is displayed even if I switch windows. Also when I **resize window**, Popup is no longer placed near button??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to tell the popup to display itself, too.

```
codePopup.IsOpen = true;
```

see [this blog](http://roecode.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/wpf-popup-control-part-1-the-quick-and-dirty-way/) for a bit more info.

[EDIT]
basically, your popup is not "tied" (or "owned") by any parent, it is independent of any other window and/or control (etc.)  Unfortunatly, there is not any easy way to get around this.

You should probably download the Popup Position Sample from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771746%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The code sample uses the class CustomPopupPlacement with a Rect object, and binds to horizontal and vertical offsets to move the Popup.

Comment: I added codePopup.IsOpen = true; Thanks its working!! But why is the popup not attaching itself to the window. I mean the popup is displayed even if I switch windows. Also when I resize window, Popup is no longer placed near button??

Comment: @GuruC, did you ever figure out how to create Popup programmatically but have it root itself properly so that popup will close when you click outside it?

Comment: that sample download is broken, a commenter there says to see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625938.aspx, but that one is missing a download link!

Answer (score 2):

If you want popup should close automatically when you click outside of it then set 
codePopup.StaysOpen = false.So that it will close when you click outside of it.